# Exchange 2007 - Public Folder Permissions

Tags: permissions, exchange, exchange-2007, public-folders

So Public Folders - I've always come into an Exchange infrastructure whereby permissions are already configured and I've merely needed to add the odd user here and there on a public folder via Powershell to give them access.

My question is - what is the default permission that would allow all users in Exchange access to a public folder, is there a group? i.e. A top level Public Folder with lots of folders beneath it - some of folders maybe restricted underneath, but at that top level, everyone should have access?

Thanks!

Comment: Some reason for the downvote would be appreciated. I see this as a perfectly fit question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public Folders use Roles to grant permissions "sets" to the PF tree. The default settings (at the root and for all new PF's) is for Anonymous users to have the "Create Items" permission and for Default users to have the Author role (Create items, Read items, Edit own items, Delete own items). The user who creates the PF (excluding the root of the PF tree) is granted the Owner role and it's  accompanying permissions.

So by default, users in AD would access the PF tree via the Defult role and users not in AD would access the PF tree via the Anonymous role.